# android x migration issue of updating gms libraries

Tags: android, firebase

I'm new to android development and just migrated to android x with my project. The files sync correctly but when I try installing it unto a device it produces the following

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.9.

this is how my build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.10.3'
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
        implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0"
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.0"
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2"
        implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
        implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.17@aar"
        implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"

        // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
    }
```

Comment: did you update your gradle version in project level dependencies??...that may also give such errors

Comment: Please post play service version